# Can not get the @Secured Method Security annotations working in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, annotations

I have done a lot of Research and to me everything looks right... but I cannot get this to work! Anyone has any idea?

No matter what I do, the relevant mapping remains public to anyone (anonymous or logged in, no matter what Role they have).

Ideally I would like to have ALL requests to be Public, except those which are annotated by @Secured() - obviously only the users with the specific roles would be allowed access to these mappings.

Is that possible?

FYI as a workaround I currently built a method "hasRole(String role)" which checks the role of the logged-in user, and throws a NotAuthorizedException (custom made) if the method returns false.

UserDetails

```
  @Override
  public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {

      List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = null;

      System.out.print("Account role... ");
      System.out.println(account.getRole());

      if (account.getRole().equals("USER")) {
          GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER");
          grantedAuthorities = Arrays.asList(grantedAuthority);
      }

      if (account.getRole().equals("ADMIN")) {
          GrantedAuthority grantedAuthorityUser = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER");
          GrantedAuthority grantedAuthorityAdmin = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN");
          grantedAuthorities = Arrays.asList(grantedAuthorityUser, grantedAuthorityAdmin);
      }

      return grantedAuthorities;
  }
```

SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthFailure authFailure;

    @Autowired
    private AuthSuccess authSuccess;

    @Autowired
    private EntryPointUnauthorizedHandler unauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    /*@Autowired
    public void configAuthBuilder(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
        builder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }*/

    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
        builder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

  private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
    HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
    repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
    return repository;
  }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
        .and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
        .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").successHandler(authSuccess).failureHandler(authFailure)
        //.and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/rest/**").authenticated()
        //.and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
        .and().addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);;
    }
```

AccountController

```
  @Secured("ROLE_USER")
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public List<Account> getAllAccounts(@RequestParam(value = "mail", required = false) String mail) {
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please could you tell us how is your mapping looks like? Is it globally on Controller defined or do you would have any method annotated with @RequestMapping(...) ?

Comment: I have annotated my AccountController class with @ RestController and @RequestMapping('rest/accounts'). I have added this code in the original post. Then I have @RequestMapping for every method seperately (e.g @RequestMapping(value=/{id}, method=RequestMethod.GET)

Comment: Can you enable mvc Security using @EnableWebMvcSecurity and try again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of Controller scoped Security with Spring HttpSecurity. Try add this to your configure Method:

```
.antMatchers("rest/accounts*").hasRole("ADMIN")
```

And if you wish ANY Request to be public (really?):

```
.anyRequest().permitAll()
```

You can additionally secure your Methodinvocation for Example in your UserDetailsService when you access it from anywhere:

```
@Secured("ROLE_USER")
public getAllAccounts(...){...}
```

Only then you have to annotate your SecurityConfig with:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
```

> In practice we recommend that you use method security at your service
>   layer, to control access to your application, and do not rely entirely
>   on the use of security constraints defined at the web-application
>   level. URLs change and it is difficult to take account of all the
>   possible URLs that an application might support and how requests might
>   be manipulated. You should try and restrict yourself to using a few
>   simple ant paths which are simple to understand. Always try to use
>   a"deny-by-default" approach where you have a catch-all wildcard ( / or
>   ) defined last and denying access. Security defined at the service
>   layer is much more robust and harder to bypass, so you should always
>   take advantage of Spring Security’s method security options.

see: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#request-matching

Comment: Hmm. Obviously the controller should be fully secured, yes. But for other APIs I want GET requests to remain public and PUT/POST/DELETE requests to be secured. I guess I could split my API into /public/, /private/ and /admin/ routes and then secure them properly using the HttpSecurity in the configure() method. That should work. But I remain curious why I can not use the @Secured annotation in my Controller. :)

Comment: Also - you are right I can secure my methods in my service classes with @Secured and this works. E.g. when I do it on my "getAllAccounts" then the security kicks in and I can only get the data when I am logged in with the correct role. But why can I only secure my Service class methods, but not my RestController? Is this intended? I found plenty of examples where people secure their Controllers as well so figured this should be possible?

Comment: It is intended and recommended. You can have a look here: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#enableglobalmethodsecurity
The method you want to secure is a handler method and is invoked by Request(Mapping). If you have additional methods in the Controller you could use @Secured Annotation.

Comment: Hey - even though I managed to fix this by securing the service class methods, I still do not understand why I can not secure my methods in my Controller class ( my GET/PUT/POST/DELETE handlers ). There is nothing in the docs that says that this should not be done and as always I see plenty of examples with this example. :S

Comment: I guess you have an annotated @RestController Class in your package. There you have your RequestMappings and belonging Handler Methods. You could secure your Url Mapping by configure for Example http.antMatchers("rest/accounts*").hasRole("ADMIN").

Comment: @Joachim  actually you can manage methods with http.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/rest/accounts*").hasRole(...

Comment: This is still a problem, did you find a solution to this @JoachimSeminck ?

Answer (score 3):

Here, I would like to add something based on the above right answer from sven.kwiotek. If in the ROLE table you still want to use "USER", "ADMIN"... the solution is also easy:

When fetch the role from database, do not forget to add "ROLE_" prefix manully, for example,

```
List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = user.getRoles().stream().map(role -> 
    new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role.getRole()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and then you could use annotation `@Secured("ROLE_USER")` in the controller method with safety.

The reason is that in the `org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter` class all roles should start with **ROLE_** prefix.