# Spring security - @PreAuthorize not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am facing an issue in using the `@PreAuthorize` annotation. Even if my user does not own the asked roles, my secured methods are executed.

My controller :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/stats/distributions")
public class DistributionStatsController {

    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('AK_LOCAL_DIST_INT', 'AK_ADMIN')")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
        produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    public @ResponseBody List<DistributionStatsResource> filter(@RequestBody DistributionStatsResource resource,  
           @RequestParam(required = false, value = "documentId") Long documentId, 
           @RequestParam(required = false, value = "distStatus") EnumDistributionStatus distributionStatus, 
           Pageable pageable, HttpServletRequest request) {
    }
}
```

Here is my spring security configuration :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    /** Defines the AuthenticationManager/providers. */
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**", "/font/**", "/icones/**", "/img/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // TODO Configure HTTP URLs and filters.
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/views/access401.html").permitAll().antMatchers("/views/admin/agent.html").hasAuthority("AK_ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/views/admin/agentDetail.html").hasAuthority("AK_ADMIN").antMatchers("/views/admin/businesses.html")
        .hasAuthority("AK_ADMIN").antMatchers("/views/admin/distributors.html").hasAuthority("AK_ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/views/admin/distributionReportList.html").hasAuthority("AK_ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/views/documentEdition/documentDetail.html").hasAnyAuthority("AK_CENTRAL_DIST", "AK_LOCAL_DIST_INT", "AK_ADMIN")

        .antMatchers("/views/home/home.html").fullyAuthenticated().antMatchers("/views/distribution/distribution.html")
        .hasAnyAuthority("AK_LOCAL_DIST_INT", "AK_ADMIN").antMatchers("/views/distribution/distributionEdit.html")
        .hasAnyAuthority("AK_LOCAL_DIST_INT", "AK_ADMIN").antMatchers("/views/admin/types.html").hasAuthority("AK_ADMIN").and()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedEntryPoint()).and().addFilter(habileFilter()).csrf().disable(); // Disable CSRF
        // protection.
    }

    /** Gives an alias to the authenticationManager. */
    @Override
    @Bean(name = "authenticationManager")
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    /** A unauthorized entry point. */
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedEntryPoint() {
        return new ForbiddenEntryPoint();
    }

    /** The user details service used by the PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider. */
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationUserDetailsService<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken> myAuthenticationUserDetailsService() {
        return new NgwisAuthenticationUserDetailsService();
    }

    /** The PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider. */
    @Bean
    public PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider() {
        PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider pro = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider();
        pro.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(myAuthenticationUserDetailsService());
        return pro;
    }

    // ---- Filters.

    /** Builds an Habile filter.
     *
     * @return the habile filter. */
    @Bean
    public RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter habileFilter() throws Exception {
        NgwisRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter filter = new NgwisRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter();
        filter.setPrincipalRequestHeader("SM_USER");
        filter.setCredentialsRequestHeader(NgwisRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.HABILE_FILTER_NAME);
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        return filter;
    }
}
```

(This class is referenced in my base configuration class)

My `RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter` class :

```
public class NgwisRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter extends RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter {

    public static final String HABILE_FILTER_NAME = "HABILE";

    /** Pour mise à disposition des informations de sécurité */
    public static final String BEAN_SECURITIES = "com.airfrance.springsecurity.securities";

    private static final org.slf4j.Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NgwisRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.class);

    // AK de l'utilisateur en fonction de ses profils
    private UserAccessKeys userAccessKeys = null;

    // Pour passer l'info au niveau de la config de spring security
    private String credentialsRequestHeader;

    @Inject
    private IAgentService agentService;

    @Inject
    private DozerBeanMapper mapper;

    /** Credentials aren't usually applicable, but if a {@code credentialsRequestHeader} is set, this will be read and used as
     * the credentials value. Otherwise a dummy value will be used. */
    @Override
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> tmp = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        User user = new User(request.getRemoteUser().toUpperCase(), "none", false, false, false, false, tmp);
        if (credentialsRequestHeader != null) {
            if (credentialsRequestHeader.equalsIgnoreCase("HABILE")) {
                try {
                    LdapBean ldBean = LdapBeanAccessor.getLdapBean(request);
                    if (ldBean != null) {
                        userAccessKeys = new UserAccessKeys(request, ldBean, agentService, mapper);
                        request.getSession().setAttribute(BEAN_SECURITIES, userAccessKeys);
                        List<String> auths = new ArrayList<String>();
                        for (GrantedAuthority auth : userAccessKeys.getAuthorities()) {
                            auths.add(auth.getAuthority());
                        }
                        logger.debug("User {} connected with authorities {}", userAccessKeys.getLogin(), StringUtils.join(auths, ", "));
                        user = new User(request.getRemoteUser().toUpperCase(), "none", true, true, true, true, userAccessKeys.getAuthorities());
                    }
                } catch (NoLdapBeanInSessionException e) {
                    logger.error("Erreur lors de la connexion de {}", request.getRemoteUser().toUpperCase(), e);
                } catch (NotProtectedGetLdapException e) {
                    logger.error("Erreur technique ", e);
                }
                if (userAccessKeys.getAgent() != null) {
                    return user;
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            } else {
                return request.getHeader(credentialsRequestHeader);
            }
        }

        return "N/A";
    }

    @Override
    public void setCredentialsRequestHeader(String credentialsRequestHeader) {
        Assert.hasText(credentialsRequestHeader, "credentialsRequestHeader must not be empty or null");
        this.credentialsRequestHeader = credentialsRequestHeader;
    }
}
```

I checked in this class we get the authorities of the logged user. Everything seems to be alright.

When I run this code with a user with just a `AK_CONSULT` role, the method is executed and no `503 ERROR` is fired.

Thanks for help.

Comment: When using XML to configure Spring, the "pre-post" must be enabled on Spring MVC context, not on Spring Security. Could this be the same issue you met (I'm not a big fan of using annotations to configure Spring)?

Comment: You could have a look here, i think that's a likewise issue and could help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29275890/can-not-get-the-secured-method-security-annotations-working-in-spring-security/29277396#29277396

Comment: It looks like my issue. But to solve it, he set the annotation on service layer, not on controllers (what I'd like). And as they say in a comment, there are lots of examples on the web where this annotation is in controllers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My collegues found the trick. 
The @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true) annotation must **not** be in the `spring-security` configuration class but **in the Servlet configuration class.**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "mypackage.spring.rest" }, excludeFilters = @Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = Configuration.class))
public class SpringRestConfiguration {

}
```

And it works !

Answer (score 4):

TLDR: `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)` on WebConfig can be used instead.

The root of the problem may be that Spring doesn't generate controller's proxy classes - by default Spring wraps into proxies only those beans which are defined as interface and Spring IoC find their implementation. If your controllers are classes which don't implement/extend anything, CGLIB proxying has to be used (I recommend reading about [Spring Proxying mechanisms](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying)), so proxy classes are generated and injected as controllers implementation - that's the place where Spring included an extra logic to respect `@PreAuthorize` and `@PostAuthorize` annotations conditions.

On Spring v5 (not Spring Boot), when `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` is used on `SecurityConfiguration` only, it won't be picked up by `WebConfig`. Moving it to `WebConfig` will enable handling pre post annotations by Spring Security as well as it will switch on CGLIB proxy mechanism.

Personally, I recommend just adding `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)` on WebConfig and leaving `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` in `SecurityConfig`.

I have tested it on Spring v5 only, but due to documentation it should work the same on Spring v4.